# An entire function with two periods

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anybody help me with this question:

> If $f(z)$ is an entire periodic function and it has to periods $2$ and $2i$, how can I find all other periods?

Answer (score 9):

If the function is entire, and has periods $2$ and $2i$, then it is bounded, and by Liouville, it is then a constant, so that any non-zero complex number is a period.

The above is well-known result in the early stages of the theory of elliptic functions. See, for example, Apostol's book "Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory" on page 5.

Comment: Umm ... not Halmos ...

Comment: Absolutely right - it is Apostol, sorry.